# Duplicate static field (Array vs String)

Tags: java, static

I have a question about the following code:

```
public Class Settings{
 public static final String WelcomeMessage= "helloworld";
 public static final String ByeMessage= "yo";

public static String[] widgets = {WelcomeMessage,ByeMessage};

}
```

The compiler complains about duplicat variables. Can I delete the 2 separate variables and still acces WelcomeMessage by Settings.WelcomeMessage? I don't need to acces it by Settings.widget[0]? And is it possible to add another variable to the WelcomeMessage variable (by for instance using a static hashtable)?

Edit: I know this code doesn't look right but it's just an example because I wondered why the compiler thinks WelcomeMessage (as a separata variable) is the same as the variable in the Widgets array.

Comment: What is the atual warning/error message from the compiler? Note that these three contents are not related, they have different names and values! "WelcomeMessage" is not a reference to static field, it's just a String "WelcomeMessage".

Comment: Are you sure? I dont' see any duplicate variables.

Comment: In your code, `Settings.WelcomeMessage` is "helloworld", while `Settings.widgets[0]` is "WelcomeMessage". They are not the same. Maybe you didn't mean to put the double quotes in the widgets array?

Comment: please post relavant code with which error matches

Comment: The definition should write class (with lowercase 'c'). Other than that my compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider java-enums in your case:

```
public enum Settings {
    WelcomeMessage ("helloworld"),
    ByeMessage   ("yo");

    public final String value;

    Settings(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

You can access now the values via `Settings.WelcomeMessage.value`. Also you get a List of the enums with `Settings.values()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've marked the fields as public static which means that yes you'll be able to access them via:

```
Settings.WelcomeMessage
```

or if you you use a static import in your class, just:

```
WelcomeMessage
```

You haven't actually used these constants in the widgets array, you've just created two new strings in there "WelcomeMessage" and "ByeMessage"

```
public static String[] widgets = {"WelcomeMessage","ByeMessage"};
```

No, if you delete the WelcomeMessage and ByeMessage constants you can't access them in that way, you'd have to go through the widgets array and access them as:

```
Settings.widgets[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use this instead:

```
public Class Settings
{
    public static final String WelcomeMessage= "helloworld";
    public static final String ByeMessage= "yo";

    public static String[] widgets = {WelcomeMessage,ByeMessage};
}
```

But this is better:

```
public Class Settings
{
    public static String[] widgets = {"WelcomeMessage","ByeMessage"};
}
```

And yes you can access `WelcomeMessage` via `Settings.widgets[0]`.

Edit: Oops - yep - of course you cannot access them by name, only index into the array.

Edit 2: If you make the field protected or private and provide 'getter' methods, then it doesn't matter to any user classes how they are implemented:

```
public Class Settings
{
    private static final String welcomeMessage= "helloworld";
    private static final String byeMessage= "yo";

    public static String getWelcomeMessage()
    {
        return welcomeMessage;
    }

    public static String getByeMessage()
    {
        return byeMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access the value via Settings.widgets.WelcomeMessage. It would be Settings.widgets[0]. EDIT: Was corrected.

Comment: @Mnementh: Corrected.  Brainfreeze!